# What is the status of stackstatus.net?

Tags: support, stackstatus

A few minutes ago (around 19:50 UTC, on 26 June 2019), the main pages of SE websites said there was a server maintenance, giving two links, one to [twitter @StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) and the other to [Stack Exchange Network Status](https://stackstatus.net/). (I tried to retrieve the URL of the maintenance page from my browser history, but it shows no more than "https://stackoverflow.com/")

Apparently, the latter is not actively maintained. The newest post is from eleven months ago (11 July 2018). What is the current status of that site?

I suppose keeping a link to an abandoned meta-website is kind of a bug. If the site is officially abandoned in favor of the Twitter account, why not remove the link to that site from the maintenance page?

Comment: I admit I opened Twitter once I noticed something wasn't working well. Instead of StackStatus I kept an eye on @Nick_Craver for the juicy details....

Comment: Yes. @ Nick_Craver is often more timely and accurate than @ StackStatus

Comment: @Yaakov what exactly is in review? There's nothing to fix in code. SE should either find employee who will have time to update it more often, or just shut it down and use only Twitter.

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard the `status-review` tag is used to surface items that we want to have a PM evaluate and schedule for potential implementation. We do want to try to find employees who will have time to update this more often (or consider shutting it down). The most that I can do right now is to start our process for addressing things like this. Thanks!

Comment: @YaakovEllis well... appreciate the effort, but since that status usually remains for years, not going to hold my breath. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard We are trying to turn over a new leaf here. Thanks for sticking with us!

Answer (score 9):

We definitely are still aware of it, but we tend to forget about it when we have maintenance and/or are in the middle of an outage.

Most of us are already logged into twitter and have [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) readily available to mention either the current outage or upcoming maintenance. [Stack Exchange Network Status](https://stackstatus.net/) is on Tumblr and we need to hunt down the username/password to login to post there, which falls through the cracks.

At this time, the most I can say is that it is still in use, and we'll try to be better about posting over there when we have maintenance upcoming or notes about an outage.

Answer (score 7):

2022 Update:

As described at "[Improvements to site status and incident communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378941/improvements-to-site-status-and-incident-communication)" the site will be updated automatically as of June 8th. The incoming automatic site can already be viewed here: https://www.stackstatus.net/