# Remove link to abandoned Stack Status blog from read-only mode banner

Tags: feature-request, broken-link, read-only, stackstatus

[image: d]

The banner suggests checking the [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) Twitter account, or the [status blog](https://stackstatus.net/).    However the latter hasn't been updated in over a year:

[image]

Not only is today's outage not mentioned, but neither is any of of the planned maintenance in the last year.  Since the blog appears to be abandoned it should be removed from the banner because it's no longer a current source of information.

Comment: Related: [What is the status of stackstatus.net?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330108/what-is-the-status-of-stackstatus-net)

Comment: It was mentioned on the right hand side of the page

Comment: @depperm a tiny low visibility box showing the most recent stackstatus tweet in the sidebar doesn't make up for the main content being abandoned.  If the blog content was replaced with a full page Twitter feed I'd have no serious problems with the site still being linked other than it being mostly pointless.

Comment: I brought this up internally for discussion. I [recently said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330108/what-is-the-status-of-stackstatus-net/330154#330154) that we would be better about posting on the blog for maintenance, but today was a bit of a one-off. We were in the middle of an outage and quickly pointed the applications at the read-only replica server so we were up, just in read-only mode. This wasn't a scheduled maintenance, it was a quick fix to get things up while we tried to recover our primary sql server, which is why nothing was added to the blog.

Comment: https://www.stackstatus.net/ is live and being updated now, just with a mandatory `www` in the URL.  With this question now overcome by events I'm not sure what should be done with it.

Comment: This is now just a dead link, trying to load https://stackstatus.net/ gives infinite loading of the browser.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars WWW DOT stackstatus DOT net does still load; and is being actively updated.  I don't know which version is in the banner.

Comment: I think they didn't fix the banner yet because it's static per site so they need to edit 180+ files,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems from 4 years ago have been addressed at some point since.  The banner has a working link to [www.stackstatus.net](http://www.stackstatus.net), and that site did contain information about last nights planned maintenance window.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

stackstatus.net is used for communicating planned maintenance that we expect will cause an outage (which we haven't had any of in a while, as you noted) and posting of public postmortems (you can expect to see one for this outage).

In the middle of an unplanned outage, we just post to Twitter instead of also drafting a blog post; see the StackStatus twitter account for the most up-to-date info, but the blog should still get updated with future planned maintenance and postmortems.

Comment: Mind getting a mod diamond on this site, so it's easier for users here to notice you're an employee without having to click through to your bio?

Comment: While your explanation is understandable, I was initially confused when I clicked the "out status blog" link in the banner and saw info that was a year old.  It took me several seconds to notice the twitter stuff on the right side (which is easy to ignore since that right side column is frequently ads on various sites).  Having a subtitle along the lines of "see twitter feed for current status" could alleviate some of this confusion.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Point taken, it's on our design team's radar to take a look at the static error pages to make them clearer and more relevant.

Comment: Is my memory off? I thought the last scheduled temporary read-only site for an upgrade was done earlier this year.

Comment: @DanNeely Yes, we did one in April 2019.